# Is there a way to combine the function body of this forEach funtion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, dry

So I have this forEach function that replaces the text in a table cell after some data is submittied. I'm replacing three different table cells based on table row and I have those separated out into three different statements.

Like this:

```
replaceData.forEach((item, i) => {
  $(`.tableData tbody tr:eq(${item.index})`)
    .children(["td:eq(6)"])
    .text(values[i] === null ? "-" : values[i]);
  $(`.tableData tbody tr:eq(${item.index})`)
    .children("td:eq(7)")
    .text(reason[i]);
  $(`.tableData tbody tr:eq(${item.index})`)
    .children("td:eq(8)")
    .text(notes[i] === null ? "-" : notes[i]);
});
```

I tried combining those three statements like this, but this didn't work. Does anyone know how I can combine these three statements, if possible? Or is the only way to achieve this is by keeping them as their own statement?

```
$(`.tableData tbody tr:eq(${item.index})`)
  .children(["td:eq(6)", "td:eq(7)", "td:eq(8)"])
  .text([
    values[i] === null ? "-" : values[i],
    reason[i],
    notes[i] === null ? "-" : notes[i]
  ]);
```

Comment: `.each(function (child) {
    child.text("something" + i)
});` might work calling on the children ?

Comment: `.end` is what you are looking for. `$(foo).children(bar).text('foobar').end().children(baz).text('foobarbaz');` https://api.jquery.com/end/

Comment: While @KevinB is correct and you *can* use chaining with `.end` to "go back"... don't.  It's hard to read, easy to get wrong and doesn't perform as well as you'd like.  Just have a variable for the repeated part `var row = $('.tableData tbody tr:eq(' + item.index + ')')` and then call off that.

Comment: ^^ absolutely agree

Comment: @KevinB which is no doubt why you didn't provide it as an answer :)

Comment: There's also some... weirdness, if it hasn't been removed. it used to keep a list of selectors, and wouldn't trim the selectors when using .end so it'd just keep adding up. Not a problem in this case since you aren't working on a persisted collection, but using a variable is cleaner and more inline with a standard non-jquery solution (aka easier to translate later)

Answer (score 0):

Doing them separately looks like the correct thing to do, putting everything in 1 single line doesn't gain you anything, and loses lots in readability, especially when using lots of ternary operations.

But you could clean up your code here by just creating a reference to the row, instead of repeating it each time.

eg.

```
replaceData.forEach((item, i) => {
  const row = $(`.tableData tbody tr:eq(${item.index})`);                   
  row.children('td:eq(6)').text(values[i] === null ? '-' : values[i])
  row.children('td:eq(7)').text(reason[i]);
  row.children('td:eq(8)').text(notes[i] === null ? '-' : notes[i])
})
```

If you have lots of columns, you could even create a simple inline function to make things even easier to follow.

eg.

```
replaceData.forEach((item, i) => {
  const row = $(`.tableData tbody tr:eq(${item.index})`);                   
  const R = c => row.children(`td:eq(${c})`);
  R(6).text(values[i] === null ? '-' : values[i]);
  R(7).text(reason[i]);
  R(8).text(notes[i] === null ? '-' : notes[i]);
})
```